# Windows 8.1 Embedded - OS folder grown to 14gb and takes entire drive

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, embedded, windows-embedded-8

I'm running Win8.1 Embedded on a small board computer, with a 16gb drive (it's built-in, can't replace it). It's an almost clean install, and the Winodws folder just keeps growing and is now 14gb. I'm pretty sure Windows Embedded should not be that big, I uninstalled almost all of Windows features and that made no difference.

Any ideas what is going on, and how to prevent Win8.1 Embedded to grow and eat my entire drive?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the disk clean feature that removes unused, temporary files, installers etc. that are simply not needed anymore? Search for `cleanmgr` in Windows and remove everything you think, you won't need. This does not harm your Windows installation, but usually removes the feature to uninstall updates for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Note:
Although the screen captures were done in Windows 10 it is still the same in Windows 8.1

Search for *cleanmgr* and open as administrator, This saves you one step and go straight to cleanup system files

[image]

Select *C:* drive

[image][image]

Select the checkboxes you wish to delete

[image]

You will be able to delete several files and also windows.old It is not recommend to remove the WindowsESD folder. This folder is used by Push Button Reset feature to reset your computer back to its original install state.

Select *OK*
Select *Delete Files*

[image]

You may be able to reclaim 1 or 2 gig of space with this method